# How can I decrypt wcrypt data from ldap?

Tags: java, encryption, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I need to fetch data from a LDAP using Java and SpringBoot. I managed to retrieve the OpenOTP data from the Ldap, but I found it's encrypted using wcrypt and I have no idea of how to decrypt it in Java and didn't find any article related to that.

Here is an example of what I get :

```
OpenOTP.TokenModel={wcrypt}DK2HtINFjxBOrjO5b7UcHLbydZgdfAvwu32jqFwSAk5=
```

I assume I will need a password to decrypt the data, but even once I have it I should probably have a bcrypt-like class for wcrypt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, it is impossible to decrypt the encrypted data out of the LDAP. The only solution is to use the Manager API and call the method `Search_Inventory_Items` to fetch the data de-crypted. Here is an example with curl :

```
curl -k\
 --user "Default\\admin:password"\
 --header "Content-Type: application/json"\
 --data '{"method":"Search_Inventory_Items", "params": {"type":"OTP Token"}, "id":0, "jsonrpc":"2.0"}'\
 https://localhost/manag/
```